# What's the equivalent in powershell of `pushd +0`, or `pushd` with no arguments, in linux shells

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, working-directory

Good luck searching for `+0` :) I did search this forum and stackoverflow for about 30 minutes and didn't find the answer.

Linux has the following command:

```
pushd +0
```

or just

```
pushd
```

with no arguments.

Which *swaps* the current directory and the top of the pushd stack.

I can't find the equivalent in powershell. Of course, I could write a script (below).

I read all the `get-help` on `set-location`, `get-location`, `push-location`, `pop-location` in powershell. Maybe I missed it.

The missing features, as I see it, are that neither `push-location` nor `pop-location` take any kind of index.

```
Get-Location -Stack | Get-Member
```

reveals that the stack is `TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PathInfoStack` not just an array. As such is has a `.peek()` to look at the top, but no index. One could:

```
(Get-Location -Stack).ToArray()[0]
(Get-Location -Stack).ToArray()[1]
```

to access various indices, but that still won't perform the swap.

You can't do a `push-location` or `ppo-location` without also changing to that directory. And you can't do a `set-location` to a stack entry (except for using the index syntax above) which would set, and not do the push or pop.

So is there anyway to do this?

Or must one write a script (function/cmdlet) to do it? Seems a lot of trouble for something that's built-in in linux shells.

A script proto demo might be:

```
PS C:\> mkdir \tmp1
PS C:\> mkdir \tmp2

PS C:\> cd \tmp1
PS C:\tmp1> pushd \tmp2
PS C:\tmp2> pushd \

PS C:\> Get-Location -Stack
   
Path  
----  
C:\tmp2
C:\tmp1

PS C:\> # script beg
PS C:\> $prvloc = Get-Location
PS C:\> $newloc = Pop-Location -PassThru
PS C:\tmp2> cd $prvloc
PS C:\> Push-Location $newloc;
PS C:\tmp2> # script end
PS C:\tmp2> Get-Location -Stack
   
Path  
----  
C:\   
C:\tmp1
```

Comment: See if this post and the answers, comments, and questions there help any with what you're doing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162443/current-directory-apparently-not-current-directory/56462392#56462392 there may be a difference from PowerShell ISE versus straight PowerShell.exe though from what I'm reading with some of those commands and the directories in the stack. Also check out `-stackname` parameter of the `Push-Location` command as per https://ss64.com/ps/push-location.html in case it helps any.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle that post says nothing about the stack, so it doesn't help. I did (say I) read all of `push-location` help including `-stackname`, however naming the stack changes nothing with respect to swapping with the top of the stack, so still at square 1.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could see if using variables with that parameter could help you define whatever logic you are trying to define to work for your need, even with a workaround variable to get you by for the immediate need. The other post indicates PowerShell_ISE behaves differently than Powershell.exe so I wanted to point that out too to ensure you test from both the ISE and straight PowerShell command line. Please confirm that you have tested with both or just one of those two.

Comment: Also, I see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869067/linux-style-pushd-in-windows may be asking for the same thing you are asking for with workarounds listed. How Linux commands work and how Windows commands work are not always the same. What you see as a hassle because you are used to doing it one way on one platform may be as easy as cake to others on the other platforms so this might just be a personal thing on the differences between the commands running on two different Operating System platforms.